# Is there a built in way to setup continuous delivery to a dedicated (NOT AZURE) server?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, tfs, azure-devops, continuous-delivery

I'm using VSTS for source control and i would like to add continuous delivery to my next project, however i have zero interest in azure. I would like to do the CD on the same platform type as my production (on a dedicated server).

Is it possible to setup CD that way from VSTS / VS2017 (i only see options for azure in the CD tool)? Or would only an on premise TFS install give me that option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can setup continuous delivery to a dedicated server which is not in Azure.

You need to see the [deployment groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops) for your case.

> When authoring an Azure Pipelines or TFS Release pipeline, you can
>   specify the deployment targets for a job using a deployment group.
>   This makes it easy to define parallel execution of deployment tasks.
>
> Deployment groups:
>
> Specify the security context and runtime targets for the agents. As
>   you create a deployment group, you add users and give them appropriate
>   permissions to administer, manage, view, and use the group.
>
> Let you view live logs for each server as a deployment takes place,
>   and download logs for all servers to track your deployments down to
>   individual machines.
>
> Enable you to use machine tags to limit deployment to specific sets of
>   target servers.

You just need to install deployment groups in your dedicated server,then you can deploy anything into your server.

Simply follow this [step-by-step tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups?view=azure-devops#create-a-deployment-group) for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can deploy to any servers other than Azure. Say you want it to be deployed to 1 of your EC2 instance from your CD pipeline, you can use the AWS tasks from the [VS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) and configure accordingly in your pipeline. As jayendran mentioned in his previous reply, you can also use Deployment Groups if you are targeting multiple machines. The Azure DevOps/TFS gives you set of pre-defined templates for CI/CD pipelines. However, you can use 3rd party tools (i.e extensions) to configure the pipeline as per your needs and still make it work.